# Strange notation using dollar sign

Tags: signature, notation

In the paper [Multi-Signatures in the Plain Public-Key Model and a General Forking Lemma](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/multisignatures-ccs.pdf), the authors *Bellare* and *Neven* use notation which looks like left arrow with dollar sign above it.

Authors provide an explanation for one variable:

> $s \overset{{\scriptstyle \$}}{\longleftarrow S}$ denotes the
>   operation of assigning to $s$ an element of $S$ chosen at random

However, in this paper they use it with multiple variables like this:

> $s_1, \ldots, s_N \overset{{\scriptstyle \$}}{\longleftarrow S}$

What is the definition of this notation? Can we chose dependent random variables for $s_i$? Do we must choose all variables $(s_1, \ldots, s_N)$ at once from the set $S^N$ with uniform distribution?

Comment: Personally, I'd probably read this as "sample a random element of S into $s_i$ independently", but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Note that uniformly choosing the individual $s_i$ independently as SEJPM suggests is equivalent to your interpretation of uniformly choosing tuples from $S^N$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$s_1, ..., s_N \stackrel{\$}{\leftarrow} S$

means coordinate-wise sampling:

$s_1 \stackrel{\$}{\leftarrow} S$

$s_2 \stackrel{\$}{\leftarrow} S$

...

$s_N \stackrel{\$}{\leftarrow} S$

Comment: This is standard notation that I've used myself

Comment: Ok, but do you remember any other paper which uses this notation?

Comment: Well, since it's Mihir's style to use this notation, it's easy to find similar examples in other paper's of his; e.g. https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/id-multisignatures.pdf

Comment: Oh-- hopefully not to belabor the point, but e.g. in this second paper I linked, see Page 5 (left column preceding Section 4). The variable X_i actually cannot be regarded as a random variable over the uniform distribution over its domain -- unless $\stackrel{\$}{\leftarrow}$ is interpreted as coordinate-wise sampling.